# Using stringstream is giving me a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, genetic-algorithm, stringstream

I'm messing around with genetic algorithms, and decided to try a new format for my fitness function. (Very trivial right now).

```
void calcfitness()
    {
        stringstream toi;
        //Max fitness 72
        int attack = 0, defense = 0,
        speed = 0, energy = 0, disease = 0;

        toi << genes [0]; toi >> attack; toi.clear();
        toi << genes [1]; toi >> defense; toi.clear();
        toi << genes [2]; toi >> speed; toi.clear();
        toi << genes [3]; toi >> energy; toi.clear();
        toi << genes [4]; toi >> disease; toi.clear();


        fitness = (attack * 2) + (defense * 2) + speed + (energy * 3) - (disease * 5);
    }
```

The dna is stored as a string which I'm trying to extract using stringstream into individual genes. When the

```
fitness =
```

line doesn't use weighting ( * 3, * 2 etc.), it works fine (although it's slower then what I was using). When I add in the weighting though, I get a segmentation fault. The program doesn't even get to main() before it happens.
How could this possibly give me a segfault? As far as I can tell, I'm not trying to access any memory that I don't own.
I searched around, and all the similar problems I could find were due to a pointer going out of scope, but again, as far as I can tell, that isn't the issue here.

Is there a better way to set this up? I tried doing

```
attack = genes [0];
```

but that assigns the char's ASCII code to attack, instead of the value itself.

Here is the start of the class that it belongs to:

```
class Being
{
int id, var1, var2, var3, var4;
string genes;

public:
double fitness;

  Being()
{
    id = env.getcurid();
    var1 = 0, var2 = 0, var3  = 0, var4 = 0;
    genes = gengenes(DNASIZE);
    fitness = 0;
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: And what is `genes`? How do you declare it?

Comment: Calcfitness() is a member function. Genes and fitness both belong to the beings class. I'll add it in above.

Comment: `genes[0] - '0'` would give you a number from a numeric character with the added bonus that it would go horribly wrong if `genes[0]` wasn't a numeric character.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm not quite sure what you mean. Like attack = genes [0] - '0';? That doesn't look legitimate. And genes will never contain anything other then numbers. It's generated using a random number generator.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  Take a look at an ascii chart, it's just simple math.

Comment: By the way, if `genes` is a valid array (or pointer) and contains a digit in character form, then you can just do e.g. `attack = genes[0] - '0';`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh, I get it. That makes sense actually :/ Thanks. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Have you checked the size of `genes`? What if it's empty? Or less than five characters?

Comment: As far as the crash goes, running it it the debugger would show you where the problem is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried that simpler version, and I'm still getting a segfault, so it doesn't have anything to do with stringstream. Joachim pileborg: I added in a check to make sure it's not empty, and I still get a segfault. And the length is a constant.

Comment: Then a debugger it is. That's your best shot at the moment. Unless you can make a more complete example the exhibits the crashing behavior to show us (also known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)). It might be that is crashes because of some unrelated stack failure, or that the `Being` class haven't been correctly constructed.

Comment: What are you doing with `fitness` outside this code?  When you add the weights, it has a larger dynamic range.  Could that be related to your problem?